# Adding a Date column based on the next row date value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Im using SQL Server 2005. From the tbl_temp table below, I would like to add an EndDate column based on the next row's StartDate minus 1 day until there's a change in AID and UID combination. This calculated EndDate will go to the row above it as the EndDate. The last row of the group of AID and UID will get the system date as its EndDate. The table has to be ordered by AID, UID, StartDate sequence. Thanks for the help.

-- tbl_temp

```
AID     UID     StartDate
1   1   2013-02-20
2   1   2013-02-06
1   1   2013-02-21
1   1   2013-02-27
1   2   2013-02-02
1   2   2013-02-04
```

-- Result needed

```
AID     UID     StartDate        EndDate
1   1   2013-02-20       2013-02-20
1   1   2013-02-21       2013-02-26
1   1   2013-02-27       sysdate
1   2   2013-02-02       2013-02-03
1   2   2013-02-04       sysdate
2   1   2013-02-06       sysdate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select top 1 dateadd(day, -1, startDate )
        from tbl_temp t2
        where t2.aid = t.aid and
              t2.uid = t.uid and
              t2.startdate > t.startdate
       ) as endDate
from tbl_temp t
```

To get the current date, use `isnull()`:

```
select t.*,
       isnull((select top 1 dateadd(day, -1, startDate )
               from tbl_temp t2
               where t2.aid = t.aid and
                     t2.uid = t.uid and
                     t2.startdate > t.startdate
               ), getdate()
              ) as endDate
from tbl_temp t
```

Normally, I would recommend `coalesce()` over `isnull()`.  However, there is a bug in some versions of SQL Server where it evaluates the first argument twice.  Normally, this doesn't make a difference, but with a subquery it does.

And finally, the use of `sysdate` makes me think of Oracle.  The same approach will work there too.

Comment: The second one works well. Just a single extra character, I took out the ")" infront of the "as endDate" so others may benefit as well. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT AID, UID, StartDate, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AID, UID ORDER BY StartDate) AS rn
    FROM tbl_temp
)
SELECT x1.AID, x1.UID, x1.StartDate, 
    COALESCE(DATEADD(day,-1,x2.StartDate), CAST(getdate() AS date)) AS EndDate
FROM x x1
LEFT OUTER JOIN x x2 ON x2.AID = x1.AID AND x2.UID = x1.UID
    AND x2.rn = x1.rn + 1
ORDER BY x1.AID, x1.UID, x1.StartDate
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d2cd/4)